# Не запускается .bat файл в планировщике задач

Tags: python, bat, планировщик-задач

Нужно запускать .bat файл 2 раза в день, сам .bat файл запускает .py скрипт который парсит сайты, но проблема в том что файл не запускается, в чем может быть проблема?

Я подозреваю что проблема в указанном пути, потому что папка пользователя на кириллице и с пробелами, как можно было бы путь адекватно задать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое .bat файла:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe" "ParcerAll.py"
pause
```

Если запускать bat напрямую в папке, то он отлично работает и запускает то что нужно

UPD 2.0:

Вот как отрабатывает bat файл если запускать его напрямую
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же поменял имя папки пользователя на латиницу без пробелов, но все равно файл не запускает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD 3.0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие-то выходные файлы получаете при обработке батника?

Comment: Запускается py файл и получаю данные с парсера, все работает как и должно, сейчас дополню вопрос

Comment: А от имени какого пользователя запускается задача в планировщике задач?

Comment: Имя пользователя К.Бояр (Второй)

Comment: Рабочую папку тоже укажите ему в настройках. Вероятно, это важно. А вообще логи системы смотрите. Да, и журнал то включите, тогда на последней вкладке будете видеть, что произошло - запустилась ли задача и с каким результатом.

Comment: ну, собственно, важно было, от имени пользователя или от имени системы :-) У них разные профили и разные path. А папка, из которой работает скрипт - в задаче задана?

Comment: Еще можно попробовать поймать вывод скрипта в файл, и тогда этот файл можно проанализировать - как при удаче, так и при неудаче. Но вот беда: то, что в линуксе делается простым > или >>, в винде, кажется, делается только при помощи какой то матери... или уже не так?

Comment: А что мне указать в рабочей папке? C:\Users\Konstantin\?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос вкладку "Общие", может это что-то даст

Comment: Ну, я лично задачи создаю от имени админа. Уже который месяц выполняются на сервере. От пользователя не запускалось

Comment: Можете в ответе показать пример как это сделать? Может поможет

Comment: Я заметил что если создать новую задачу и попробовать запустить, то bat файл запускает, но выдает ошибку

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe: can't open file 'ParcerAll.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, посидев парочку часов я понял как решить мою проблему, мои действия:

1. Я сделал абсолютно новый процесс, потому что тот видимо багнулся и что-то шло постоянно не так.
2. Переименовал bat файл убрав `_`
3. После того как указал полный путь к файлу, добавил еще и рабочую папку
4. Переименовал папку пользователя, заменив кириллицу и пробелы на латиницу без пробелов

В итоге запуск свойства этой задачи выглядели вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скрин того что все работает как надо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]